# Start application with content via NFC NDEF message

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I need to transmit data via NFC to other device and third-party app. Problem that is neither of targeted apps, that able to view my content, does define `intent-filter` with any `android.nfc.action`. But they actually define filters to view my data. Is it possible to open such third-party app by NFC bump with my data?

Third party apps define filters with

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

and variety data elements such as

```
<data android:mimeType="{MYMIME}" android:scheme="{content|file|https}"/>
<data android:host="{MYHOST}" android:pathPrefix="/view/" android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:host="*" android:pathPattern="{.*\\.MYEXTENSION|.*\\..*\\.MYEXTENSION}" android:scheme="{content|file|https|http}"/>
<data android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern="{.*\\.MYEXTENSION|.*\\..*\\.MYEXTENSION}" android:scheme="{content|file|https|http}"/>
<data android:scheme="{MYSCHEME}"/>
<data android:host="*" android:pathPattern="/.*" android:scheme="{MYSCHEME}"/>
```

Does android define any intermediate to convert `TNF_MIME_MEDIA` NDEF record to some kind of local uri resource? Or maybe I can structure NFC payload other way, not necessary with NDEF protocol? 
In worst scenario I'm able to use AAR record to open specific app, but it only opens on main activity (not with my content).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking? Do you want to open a specific app when a tag is read?

Comment: I want to open my file with any app that supports viewing this type of file by the moment when tag had been read.